# Pareto optimality edgeworth box

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

I'm very new to latex, and I would like to have a graph that looks like the one I attach.
The idea is to have the Pareto set of an Edgeworth box identified clearly, along with the contract curve, the initial endowment (omega), and the indifference curves.

My starting point in the code comes from the solution to a question I saw in this page, but I can't figure how to pick up the code from there to change it and make it look to what I need

[Edgeworth Box of Pareto efficiency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172046/edgeworth-box-of-pareto-efficiency)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but close enough that you can modify it yourself.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (8,6);
\begin{scope}[->,>=latex,thick]
    \draw (A) -- +(9,0);
    \draw (A) -- +(0,7);
    \draw (B) -- +(-9,0);
    \draw (B) -- +(0,-7);
\end{scope}
\node[below left] at (A) {$O_1$};
\node[above right] at (B) {$O_2$};

\draw[dashed, thick, postaction={decorate, decoration={markings,
    mark=between positions 0.2 and 0.8 step 0.2 with {
        \draw[black,solid] (-0.3,0.7) to[out=-50,in=90] (0,0) 
            to[out=-90,in=50] (-0.3,-0.7);
        \draw[red,solid] (0.3,0.7) to[out=-130,in=90] (0,0) 
            to[out=-90,in=130] (0.3,-0.7);
        }}}, name path=pareto] (A) to[out=50,in=-160] (B);

\coordinate (C) at (5.5,2.5);
\coordinate (D) at (3.5,5.5);

\draw[black, thick, shorten >=-20,shorten <=-10, name path=f2] 
(C) to[out=100,in=-10] (D);
\draw[red, thick, shorten >=-10,shorten <=-10, name path=f1] 
(C) to[out=170,in=-90] (D);
\fill[black] (C) circle (2pt) node[above right] {$\omega$};

\path [name intersections={of=pareto and f1,by=F1}];
\path [name intersections={of=pareto and f2,by=F2}];

\begin{scope}
    \clip (F1) rectangle (F2); 
    \draw[line width=2pt] (A) to[out=50,in=-160] (B);
\end{scope}
    
\draw[->,>=latex] (4,2) node[below]{\footnotesize 
    \begin{tabular}{c}Contract\\curve\end{tabular}} 
    to[out=90,in=-70] (4.2,4);

\draw[->,>=latex] (5.5,6.5) node[above]{\footnotesize Pareto set} to[out=-60,in=120] (7,5.7);
\draw[->,>=latex] (5.5,6.5) to[out=-70,in=120] (5.5,5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly it. Thanks!